# Adding the contents of particular index positions in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

So i'm a newbie I hope you can help apologies for my errors. I've been working on some small tasks for a course i'm doing. What i was wondering is if it is possible to reference two index positions and add the contents (assuming they are integers). I've found several places i thought this might be a useful model to use- particularly for a Fibonacci generator I'm trying to make. so for an initial generator i have the first few values then i would like to reference the index element to create a recursive pattern so i can get the user to choose how long they would like it to be (of length n).

```
    Fib_list = [0,1,1]

    n = input ("Please choose a number")

    l = (len(Fib_list)

    j = Fib_list[-1]+ Fib_list [-2]

    while l <= n:

       Fib_list.append(j)

   print(Fib_list)
```

Comment: `j = Fib_list[-1]+[-2]` Are you looking for `j = fib_list[-1] + fib_list[-2]` ?

Comment: yes please :) apologies for the delay!

Comment: Problem solved, then?

Comment: hmm  i thought so... although when i run my code it reports that the syntax is invalid and points to the j? is this possibly an error in my code elsewhere? many thanks

Comment: Please share the error output, then.

Comment: File "main.py", line 7
    j = Fib_list[-1]+ Fib_list [-2]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: my apologies for the late reply

Comment: ok thaks its working although for some reason only appends one diget to the list... probably somehting i'll have to work on  thanks again

Comment: _ok thaks its working although for some reason only appends one diget to the list..._ That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra bracket at line `l = (len(Fib_list)`, why '(' in the beginning? Remove the starting bracket '(', it should be `l = len(Fib_list)`. Your input `n` is string so first you need to convert it as int as `n = int(n)` or you could do it during input as `n = int(input("Please choose a number"))`. Now your code will not give any error.

Comment: hmm good question.. the short answer is it is the way ive been shown in examples? I shall give it a try (bear with me ill update) thanks Manish

Comment: ok thaks its working although for some reason only appends one diget to the list... probably somehting ill have to work on 